# Rename elements of a list

Tags: r, list, rename

I am creating a large list pulling variables from a dataframe. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame (A-Imp = c(4,8,2,4,3),
      A-Rea = c(4,4,5,6,7),
      B-Imp = c(3,2,6,5,8),
      B-Rea = c(1,2,6,7,9),
      C-Imp = c(4,8,6,6,10),
      C-Rea = c(6,8,5,1,9),
      D-Imp = c(1,6,4,8,8),
      D-Rea = c(3,3,6,1,10))

groups <- list(
   "groupA" <- c("A-Imp", "A-Rea"),
   "groupB" <- c("B-Imp", "B-Rea"),
   "groupC" <- c("C-Imp", "C-Rea"),
   "groupD" <- c("D-Imp", "D-Rea"))
```

What I want to do is to rename the entries of every vector, maintaining only the last part of the name. It would look like something like this:

```
groups <- list(
   "groupA" <- c("Imp", "Rea"),
   "groupB" <- c("Imp", "Rea"),
   "groupC" <- c("Imp", "Rea"),
   "groupD" <- c("Imp", "Rea"))
```

Since it is a very long list I don't want to do it manually. Any ideas on how I can proceed?

Answer (score 2):

```
groups <- lapply(groups, sub, pattern = "[A-Z]-", replacement = "")

str(groups)
List of 4
 $ : chr [1:2] "Imp" "Rea"
 $ : chr [1:2] "Imp" "Rea"
 $ : chr [1:2] "Imp" "Rea"
 $ : chr [1:2] "Imp" "Rea"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sub` you can remove everything until underscore.

```
result <- lapply(groups, function(x) sub('.*-', '', x))
result

#[[1]]
#[1] "Imp" "Rea"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Imp" "Rea"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Imp" "Rea"

#[[4]]
#[1] "Imp" "Rea"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map()`:

```
Map(function(x){gsub("^\\w\\-", "", x)}, groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` and `str_remove`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map(groups, str_remove, pattern = ".*-")
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#[1] "Imp" "Rea"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Imp" "Rea"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Imp" "Rea"

#[[4]]
#[1] "Imp" "Rea"
```